# What is the purpose of the optional <type> argument in \definecolor & friends?

Tags: color

The [`xcolor` package](//ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) defines the commands `\definecolor`, `\providecolor`, and `\colorlet` as follows:

```
\definecolor      [<type>]{<name>}{<model-list>}{<spec-list>}

\providecolor     [<type>]{<name>}{<model-list>}{<spec-list>}

\colorlet         [<type>]{<name>}{<num model>}{<color>}
```

The [documentation for the `xcolor` package](//texdoc.net/pkg/xcolor) is not clear, however, about the meaning of the optional `<type>` argument for these commands. Does anybody know the purpose of this argument?

Comment: Did you see page 20 in `xcolor` doc?

Comment: Yes, and it still isn't clear to me what <type> does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option is only relevant for the postscript route. Compile this with latex +dvips:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[prologue]{xcolor}
\definecolor      [named]{COLORNAMED}{rgb}{0.3,0.4,0.5}
\definecolor      [ps]{COLORPS}{rgb}{0.2,0.7,0.1}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{COLORNAMED}{some text}
\textcolor{COLORPS}{some text}
\end{document}
```

Then you can look in the ps-file:

The first color gives in the page stream something like this:

```
 XC@COLORNAMED 639 523 a Fa(some)27 b(text)
```

and earlier in the file a declaration for this name (along with other names):

```
 /XC@COLORNAMED{0.3 0.4 0.5}XCrgb
```

The second color uses in the page stream the values:

```
 0.2,0.7,0.1 TeXcolorrgb 28 w(some)g(text)p
```

Side remark: As color names can end up like this in the postscript it is important that they don't contain spaces or other problematic chars.

Comment: Thanks. So `named` and `ps` are the only two possible inputs for the `<type>` argument?

Comment: that is what the table 4 says, I didn't check the code.